# sip parses and libraries?

Tags: c, sip

gcc 4.4.4 c89

Does any one know any sdp parses. That I can link to my application. Currently we are developing a SIP project. However, we need to parse the SDP for incoming/answering.

However, we don't have much time to implement. So just wondering if there are some simple ones out there they are easy and quick to work with.

Our application is written in c.

Many thanks for any advice,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [FreeSDP](http://www.nongnu.org/freesdp/). But it is distributed under GPL

Comment: There is also pjsip. However, I will accept this as an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

My company, RADVISION, offers a full commercial SIP stack written in C that includes an SDP parser. It might not be exactly what you're looking for, but it might reduce your development effort even further: http://www.radvision.com/Products/Developer/VoIP-Developer-Tools/SIP-Developer-Suite/

Comment: Thanks for the comment. However, we are only a small company. We were only looking for a free one. I think that might be too expensive.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't looked into open source stacks, but I would suspect that most SIP stacks would include an SDP parser.  They are pretty closely tied together.